# Turn off gzip on nginx on custom header

Tags: nginx

I'm attempting to configure NGINX in such a way that I can use client side download progress with gzip enabled. Unfortunately browser support for download progress with gzip is rather lacking. I've settled on a way to get around it by making a HEAD request to get the length of the uncompressed file, but to do that I need to turn off gzip for that one request. I was thinking that I could do this in NGINX:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  root /path/to/app;
  index index.html;   
  underscores_in_headers on;
  location / {
    if ($http_x_disable_gzip) {
      gzip off;
    }
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

If I send the header of X-Disable-Gzip or X_DISABLE_GZIP, I still get a gzip'd response.

Long story short: how do (or can) I use a custom header to selectively disable gzip responses?

Comment: What did you send as the Accept-Encoding: header?

Comment: Accept-Encoding: identity should work ^

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I'm sending this from a web page (XMLHttpRequest), and it does not allow me to modify that header. The browser sends "gzip, deflate, sdch, br"

Comment: A list of disallowed headers with XHR: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name

Comment: Is it real server block? How did you check?

Comment: @AlexeyTen: Can you please rephrase? I'm using Chrome's dev mode to inspect the headers to/from the server.

Comment: Show full server block config

Comment: There's nothing else except the port that it's listening on and the server name. I will update it with some dummy data.

Comment: It's just serving static files. The configuration has been updated.

Comment: If you are trying to do "client side download progress" then why do you care what the uncompressed size is? It sounds like that should be completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Michael: Because XHR only reports the uncompressed size as it downloads. It's annoying.